# Selecting column value dependent on parent ID without need for PHP loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a table that holds among other things:

```
ID | pagetitle | parent
1  |  Page 1   |   0
2  |  Page 2   |   1
3  |  Page 3   |   2
```

I am trying to select all the pages, along with their parent's pagetitle.

Currently I am looping through the results in PHP, grabbing the pagetitles for those pages with parents, and it looks pretty ugly:

```
function showPageParent($pageid) {
    do {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT parent FROM pages WHERE id=" . qt($pageid));
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $crumbs[] = $row['parent'];
            $pageid1 = $row['parent'];
        }
    } while($pageid1!=0);
    sort($crumbs);
    foreach($crumbs as $crumb) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,pagetitle FROM pages WHERE id=" . $crumb);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $out .= $row['pagetitle'] . " > ";
        }
    }
    if(count($crumbs) < 2) {
        return showPageTitle($pageid);
    } else {
        return $out;
    }
}
```

It works, but it is very old code, I am in the processes of re-writing a LOT of this sytem, and would love to pretty this thing up with one call to the database to return something like this:

```
ID | pagetitle | parent-pagetitle
```

Is this possible using inner selects?

**edit**

I'd like to point out, I am not the original author of the PHP, I am aware it's poorly written :p

Comment: maybe u should also replace use of mysql function. pdo, mysqli is the better alternative choices than mysql function

Comment: I am rewriting using ezSQL, there are no mysq_* functions in the new code as I am slowly re-writing it.

Comment: I would not have minded using PDO however, It was not my call to use ezSQL, I work in a team of 4 and they voted ezSQL, it's not terrible.

Comment: It looks like you can use PDO with ezSQL, just avoid the `ezSQL_mysql`  class.

Comment: I'll make it a point to push that tomorrow at the dev meeting. I'm sure they won't have an issue with using PDO with ezSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.id
     , p.title
     , pp.id
     , pp.title parentitle
  from pages p
  left
 outer
  join pages pp
    on p.parent = pp.id
```

You can add another join for each level of depth, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you're trying to manage hierarchical data in a non-hierarchical database. One of the better ways to model this appropriately is the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPTT), which is very nicely explained [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). That article also shows you why hierarchical data in a simple adjacent list model (your current model) is virtually impossible to work with. Also look at [materialized paths](https://communities.bmc.com/communities/docs/DOC-9902) or [nested interval](http://www.sigmod.org/publications/sigmod-record/0506/p47-article-tropashko.pdf) tree models.

Comment: I do like this idea, I am not aware the scope or budget for this project. It's up too the client if they want to re-structure their database....and if they want to pay for it. Thank you for the links.